# Colors are messed up in the console because of this one line of code

Tags: c#, console, midi

So recently I've been making a Console MIDI player, and I have came across a huge problem. Colors won't work properly just because of this one line of code:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
```

And whenever I remove this line of code, colors seem to work normally. Here's an example of what I mean:

[With "Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEoX8.png)

[Without "Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RybnG.png)

Oh yeah btw here's the code that handles all the printing and color encoding:

```
    var noteDisplay = new Thread(() => {
        Console.Clear();
        while (!midiEnded) {
            Console.MoveBufferArea(0, 0, keyboardWidth, Console.WindowHeight - 1, 0, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", notes.ToArray()));
            Thread.Sleep((int)(4*(1/playbackSpeed)));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0);
        }
    });

//...

public static string EncodeToRGB(List<int> rgbList) {
    int res1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbList.Count; i++) res1 = (res1 << 8) | rgbList[i];
    return res1.ToString("X");
}
```

And the weirdest thing I have discovered was this:
[Weird console behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsQfT.png)

Seriously, I have no idea why this happens. Do any of you guys know why exactly this happens?

Comment: did you try Console.SetCursorPosition(1,1);  ?

Comment: If you are moving the cursor yourself, you probably want to `.Write()` rather than `.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to simply use [Colorful Console](https://github.com/tomakita/Colorful.Console). I have used it quite extensively and it's given me zero problems.

Comment: Another huge problem,
"The type of namespace 'Formatter' could not be found."

Comment: `Formatter` isn't a namespace, it's a class (assuming you're referring to `Colorful.Formatter`).